# Looking for hard cell segmentation problem

Tags: bioinformatics, image-processing

I am a physicist working on a new image segmentation technique, and I would like to test it by segmenting some images with low-refined cells on a noisy background... Do you know where I could find such images? Thanks!

Comment: What type of microscopy? We have tons of phase contrast images of adherent human cells in our lab, and I have always wanted to try segmentation for automatic cell counting ... If interested, email me at roland.nilsson@ki.se !

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks for the reply! I'm gonna send you an email ;-)